# Cardinal Arithmetic

Tags: analysis

I'm reading in some course notes for my university's Real analysis course that, where

$$ X \cap Y $$ is non empty, that

$$|X| + |Y| = |X \cup Y|$$

But this doesn't make sense. What if X = Y? Wouldn't the cardinality of $$|X \cup Y|$$ be $$|X|$$?

Answer (score 3):

The assumption should be that $X \cap Y$ is *empty*, not non-empty.